# Why no error when accessing a DOM element that doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs with partial views in them. Why would a reference to a div that doesn't exist not show some kind of error? For example, I only have one taskN div right now:

```
<div id="task1">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/PartialViews/TaskDosCommand.cshtml")
</div>
```

This is my jQuery to show the div:

```
$('#task' + task.PrestoTaskType).show();
```

When `task.PrestoTaskType` is 1, the task1 div correctly displays. However, when `task.PrestoTaskType` is anything but 1, like 2, then nothing displays (which is good), but there is no error; no error shows on the web page, and nothing displays in the Chrome developer tools console:

[image]

Shouldn't some kind of error display when accessing a DOM element that doesn't exist?

Comment: Think if `$('selector')` meaning, "prepare the set of DOM elements matching this selector."  Sets can be empty, so an empty set isn't an error. Subsequent calls like `.show()` mean, "do this for every element in the set."  Again, there's no problem if it's an empty set. You can always explicitly check `.length` of a jQuery object to see if it is in fact empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because what jQuery does is `.show()` *all elements that the jQuery object wraps*. If that's no elements at all, then so be it.

That's precisely a monad-like aspect of jQuery that makes it so useful: imagine the code you 'd have to write if things didn't work that way:

```
var $whatever = $(...);
if ($whatever.length) $.doSomething();
```

This is simply worse: you need to introduce a variable (in order to avoid waste) *and* a conditional... for what gain exactly?

If you **want** to see what jQuery matched you can do that very easily with `.length` as above, perhaps also using `.filter` in the process.

Comment: It's a benefit, certainly, but I always assumed the reason there was no error is because jQuery *always* returns a jQuery object, which has the `show()` (or whatever) method?

Comment: @DavidThomas: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

One of the nice things about jQuery is that all jQuery elements return a collection, whether that is 0, 1, or many elements. This is convenient because you don't need to check the size of the collection or wrap it in an array yourself when you want to call methods on it (`each` for example doesn't break for 0-1 elements).

While what you're talking about is frustrating in this particular case, it is better for jQuery to work this way so you don't have to do those sorts of checks everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to branch code based on the existence of such an element, you can do this:

```
var task = $('#task' + task.PrestoTaskType);

if (task[0]) {
    task.show();
} else {
    // task not found
    // take appropriate steps
}
```

The `[0]` accessor will return the first DOM element in the jQuery object or `undefined` if the jQuery object is empty. Since your jQuery object was constructed with an ID selector, it either contains exactly one DOM element or it's empty.